# Delete all rows per group except one using CTE

Tags: sql, mariadb, common-table-expression, sql-delete

I'm using MariaDB, and I am trying to make two things, both are failing.

(1) I'm trying to delete all duplicated items, but maintaining one record.

```
WITH CTE AS (
  SELECT asin, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY asin ORDER BY created_at) AS n
  FROM asin_list
)
DELETE
FROM CTE
WHERE n > 1
```

This returns the following error:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
> corresponds to your MariaDB.

(2) As a workaround from above query I was trying to insert all duplicated ASINs into a table, having as a goal to select max(asin) later on and delete it.

```
WITH CTE AS (
  SELECT asin, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY asin ORDER BY created_at) AS n
  FROM asin_list
)
INSERT INTO temp1 *
FROM FROM CTE
WHERE n > 1
```

But this returns the same error. Can you please, help me fixing this?

Comment: "As n" seems to be the problem. Also the table name in order by is wrong

Comment: Are you sure it's supported in Mariadb?  This bug report suggests the first part (delete from cte) isn't at present... https://jira.mariadb.org/browse/MDEV-18511

Comment: Doesn't work. same issue. The select works. The delete doesn't.

Answer (score 1):

You could write the statement as:

```
select * -- delete
from asin_list as newer
where exists (
    select *
    from asin_list as older
    where older.asin = newer.asin and (
        older.created_at < newer.created_at or
        older.created_at = newer.created_at and older.pri_key < newer.pri_key
    )
)
```

Comment: I have situations, where the created_at of both asins, have the same created_at date

Comment: In case of tie, you could keep the row with lowest value in primary key. I have updated the answer but i am half asleep so triple check the logic.

Comment: the query with the select, works amazing. when i switch it to delete i get the same error i was getting before with WITH: '1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'as newer
where exists ('

Comment: Not sure why, pretty much standard sql. Try (a) remove as newer alias (b) in sub query replace newer with asin_list (c) as older needs no change.

Comment: I've read its a MariaDb limitation... :(

Answer (score 0):

Try to add “;” before  “WITH”. Something like:

```
;WITH CTE AS ( SELECT asin , row_number() OVER(PARTITION BY asin ORDER BY asin_list.created_at) AS n FROM asin_list ) delete from CTE WHERE n > 1
```

Let me know

Comment: If not, try to replace “WHERE n” with “WHERE CTE.n”. Let me know

Comment: CTEs don't begin with ";"... Previous statement does need to end properly though.

Comment: Doesn't work. same issue. The select works. The delete doesn't.

Comment: Try to follow the Salaman solution's above